# Send data from div to controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is that possible instead of using `<input name="...."/>` I get my value from `div` or `span` etc. ?

currently I get my data directly from database, base on product id, but as my product might have discount that will show different price with what is saved in my database and I cannot show it as `input` so i need to pass it through `div` or `span` etc.

## code:

here is my code now:

```
public function addingItem(Request $request, $id)
    {
      $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    Cart::add(array(
            'id' => $product->id,
            'name' => $product->title,
            'price' => $product->price,  // this comes directly from products table
    ));
}
```

[image: screen1]

with my code i always will get `45.325` but I need to get `35.325` during discount time.

That's why i need to pass it through `div` and cannot use `input` here.

any idea?

Comment: Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: @aldrin27 updated

Comment: show us your view as well please

Comment: you could use data-attributes? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: I'm assuming here that you want to submit a form. You can use javascript to do a post request using javascript, so you can put the data anywhere you want as long as js submits it.

Comment: @Ibu correct. do you have any sample of it?

Comment: Why not use a hidden input field?

Comment: @fubar not interested to print same data several time in my blade.

Comment: @mafortis check ajax requests.

Comment: @mafortis - so you're going to engineer another grossly more complicated solution to save adding one more line of code to your view? Wow.

Comment: @fubar base on `imsop` answer which i found it reasonable, to avoid users cheating on discounted price yes i preferred to get that price fully in back-end instead of return it from front-end.

Comment: @mafortis - you should definitely not rely on data from the browser when determining price. But your question neglected to mention why you were doing this, only what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: @fubar I was trying to accomplish getting different price in different conditions and in my mind was to get that difference from front-end (which was my question) then i received comment which opened my mind to better way and i did it. the purpose of asking questions here is to get what you need but in best way interest isn't it?

Comment: @mafortis - That's fair enough. I'm glad you found a better solution to your problem.

Comment: @fubar thanks dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLVED

well I decided to bring my codes to controller instead of using ajax or other ways, here is how I've done it:

```
$discounts = Discount::all();
      $mytime = Carbon::now();
      //get discounted price or normal price of product
      $price = $product->discounts;
      if($price->count() > 0 ) {
        foreach($discounts as $disc){
          if($disc->value_to >= $mytime) {
            $price = $product->price - $disc->amount;
          }
        }
      }else{
        $price = $product->price;
      }
```

Hope it help others.

Comment: Just a note that this should all be encapsulated into a shared method, like `$product->getDiscountedPrice()` so you don't have to copy and paste this all over your code, and keep all the copies in sync when you add more rules to your discounts.

Answer (score 3):

As far as your PHP code is concerned, data doesn't come from any particular part of a page, it comes from the HTTP request sent by the browser. An HTML form is just the simplest way to get the browser to add some data to that request. This may seem like nitpicking, but it has important consequences.

First, it means that what you are asking for is absolutely possible. You just need to write some JavaScript to run in the browser and tell the browser to add that value to the request. A simple way would be to have a hidden input field on the form and set the value in the JavaScript, but you can also create a completely custom request and send it to the server (AJAX).

Second, though, it means that any user can submit any data to your application by telling their browser to submit their choice of value not yours. Consequently, you have to be very careful of what data you trust, and trusting the browser to send you a price sounds like a really bad idea. What's to stop someone giving themselves a 100% discount by editing the value on the page?

Somewhere, you know what discounts you're offering. That discount is a core part of your application, so however the view knows what discount to show, the rest of the application should be able to know the same way. This probably means moving some code out of your view into a new function, which can be used by various parts of the application; that makes each use more readable, and means you don't have to change it in lots of places if the requirements get more complex.

Comment: so what do you suggest? because using input and ajax both has ability of manipulation. should i convert my blade data such as `if` `foreach` etc into controller? or what?

Comment: (comment incorporated into answer)