# laravel getting error on empty request

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I get error below while trying to add item to my cart:

> Darryldecode \ Cart \ Exceptions \ InvalidItemException
>   validation.numeric

The error comes from this part of my code:

```
$customAttributes = [];
      if(!empty($request->attr)){
          foreach($request->attr as $sub) {
          // find the suboption
              $sub = Suboption::find($sub);
              if (!empty($sub->id)) {
                  $itemCondition1 = new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(array(
                      'name' => $sub->title,
                      'value' => $sub->price,
                      'type' => 'additional',
                      'target' => 'item',
                  ));

                  array_push($customAttributes, $itemCondition1);
              }
          }
      }
```

and it take place in here:

```
Cart::add(array(
        'id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $product->title,
        'price' => $price,
        'quantity' => $request->input('quantity'),
        'attributes' => $weightArray,
        'conditions' => $customAttributes,  //here
));
```

The `$customAttributes` code supposed to get data IF `product does have those information And user chose any of it` and suppose to `ignore` if product doesn't have any of those info or user didn't chose any of it.

### Issue is

The code expect data no matter what, product does have that info or not, user selected any or not, even if user select that data still i get error above.

## Demo

https://i.stack.imgur.com/csUaH.jpg

any idea why is that?

## UPDATE

I figured my issue comes from `'price' => $price,` in my add method where i get my `$price` like:

```
$price = $product->discounts;
      if($price->count() > 0 ) {
        foreach($discounts as $disc){
          if($disc->value_to >= $mytime) {
            $price = $product->price - $disc->amount;
          }
        }
      }else{
        $price = $product->price;
      }
```

this part supposed to get product price if there is no discount, and get discounted price if there is.

How I get to this line of code? [here is it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737812/send-data-from-div-to-controller-in-laravel)

Comment: Based on the error, I'm assuming the price is treated as a string instead of a number?

Comment: @BrianPutt how to fix it?

Comment: I'd recommend trying ```var_dump``` to verify its type, but in general, multiplying by 1 will convert strings to int|double|float depending on what you need.

Comment: @BrianPutt I updated my question

Comment: I would create a variable $discounts and set the initial price to the product price. It's possible that the price is not set correctly as the price variable may not get set to a single value in that foreach statement

Comment: @BrianPutt I assume not, would you mind help me to get it right? maybe share an answer?

Answer (score 0):

## SOLVED

I used hidden field and got my data from front-end instead of controller method.